# What is the meaning of the "/" slash in such as the directive “allow from 000.111.222.333/444” in a .htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ip, cidr

For example, I have these directives in my *.htaccess* file:

```
<Limit GET HEAD POST>
order deny,allow
allow from 1.37.0.0/16
allow from 23.226.128.240/31
allow from 23.234.68.64/27
allow from 23.234.80.200/29
allow from 23.234.91.160/27
deny from all
</Limit>
```

- What is the meaning of the *"/"* slashes therein?
- And how can we convert them into `mod_rewrite` directives?

Answer (score 1):

That value defines the number of bits to mask off the most significant bits in the address. See the [Wikipedia page on CIDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#IPv4_CIDR_blocks) for more details.

For example, if I specify `10.0.0.0/8`, that means `10.*` is allowed (or denied, whatever hte case may be). That's because each octet in an IPv4 address has 8 bits (1 byte, a.k.a. octet). If I specify `192.168.0.0/24`, that masks off the first 24 bits (first 3 octets) and `192.168.0.*` is allowed or denied.

Comment: As for `mod_rewrite`, I'd recommend splitting that part into a separate question. And maybe asking on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) or [superuser.com](http://superuser.com). I think only the CIDR/netmask portion of the question is on-topic here on stackoverflow.

Comment: So, what will be the **RegExp** for `23.234.68.64/27`? Please give me a sample.. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure matching IP addresses based on regular expressions makes a lot of sense. A `/27` isn't on an octet boundary so it would be difficult to write a regular expression. Also, a dotted-quad IP address is not the only way to write an IP address. (an IP address is just a number, and it's perfectly valid to write `2130706433` instead of `127.0.0.1`.) Regular expressions are better at matching text, like maybe the resource portion of a URL.